# error-message when shutting down system, yet shutdown works well

Tags: shutdown

when shutting down my system I use the terminal-command `shutdown -H -P +0` or `poweroff`. For me that´s a good way of achieving that goal
and it works well.
I changed my grub-config from

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth"`

in order to get
screen output of the logs.

An here I saw an entry reading **"failed unmounting /home"** (in red). After that came some more messages which all were O.K. Everything else was in green with an "O.K." in front.

I don´t know why I get this message because the shutdown works well. In fact it shuts down so fast that it´s virtually impossible to read
the rest of the messages.

Any ideas what might be the cause of the **"failed unmounting /home"**-message?

Journalctl says:

```
Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e umount[25556]: umount: /home: das Ziel wird gerade benutzt.     
Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/rosika/28BC-DAFC... 
Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/rosika/f14a27c2-0b49-4607-94ea-2e56bbf76fe1...     
Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1]: home.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32 Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /home
```

So basically a process seems to be running which prevents unmounting.

Further info:

```
Apr 05 18:16:17 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1552]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Apr 05 18:16:17 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1552]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

P.S.:
my system: Linux/Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, 64 bit

Comment: please include relevant parts of `journalctl` into the question and it is a bug. You get this if there is a service using /home/ that was not stopped before the shutdown started. Example: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6956 Identify the service that was not stopped and file a bug report :)

Comment: Tnx. Journalctl says: `Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e umount[25556]: umount: /home: das Ziel wird gerade benutzt.
Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/rosika/28BC-DAFC...
Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/rosika/f14a27c2-0b49-4607-94ea-2e56bbf76fe1...
Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1]: home.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Apr 05 18:16:19 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /home` So basically a process seems to be running which prevents unmounting. But I´m bit at a loss here.

Comment: >> Identify the service that was not stopped and file a bug report...... Not sure how to do that.

Comment: I found: `Apr 05 18:16:17 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1552]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 05 18:16:17 rosika-Lenovo-H520e systemd[1552]: xfce4-notifyd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.` Could that be the culprit?

Comment: edit it into the question  please. and yes.

Comment: Curious thing though: There doesn´t seem to be a xfce4-notifyd.service running on my system. Neither`service --status-all` nor `systemctl list-units --type service` lists it.

Comment: Odd: `systemctl status xfce4-notifyd.service Unit xfce4-notifyd.service could not be found` . But: `systemctl --user status xfce4-notifyd
● xfce4-notifyd.service - XFCE notifications service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service; static; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-04-06 12:43:01 CEST; 2h 54min ago
 Main PID: 1717 (xfce4-notifyd)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/xfce4-notifyd.service
           └─1717 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd [...]`

Comment: I issued the command `systemctl --user stop xfce4-notifyd` before shutting down. The command itself worked but when shutting down I get the same error-message: "failed unmounting /home"